# How can I sum two different columns at once where one contains Decimal objects in pandas?

Tags: python, pandas

I have a dataframe that I want to aggregate the sums for for two different columns. Here is a `df.head(5)` of my original dataframe.

```
   price           name  quantity transaction_amount
pk                                                  
48  1.00      Product 1         1               1.00
48  1.00      Product 1         4               4.00
63  1.00      Product 2         2               2.00
63  1.00      Product 2         3               3.00
63  1.00      Product 2         1               1.00
```

I want to group them by `pk`, which is the database primary key of the products and get the sums of the `transaction_amount` column and the `quantity` amount columns. But when I do `df.groupby(['pk', 'name']).sum()` I get this:

```
                          quantity
pk name                           
48 Product 1                   543
63 Product 2                 17234
38 Product 3                  4014
39 Product 4                 11053
40 Product 5                 13406
```

Where's the `transaction_amount` column? `transaction_amount` is the `quantity` in the transaction and `price` of that item in that transaction. This can change per transaction if there's a discount applied or whatever. We need to record what was charged for the item at the time of purchase. So my desired outcome will have the `quantity`(total quantity), `transaction_amounts`(total amount), `name`, and `pk` like this:

```
                          quantity  transaction_amount
pk name                           
48 Product 1                   543              543.00
63 Product 2                 17234           89,000.93
38 Product 3                  4014            2,000.32
39 Product 4                 11053           25,000.36
40 Product 5                 13406            6,000.12
```

I read the [documentation for `.sum()`](http://pandas-docs.github.io/pandas-docs-travis/generated/pandas.DataFrame.sum.html#pandas.DataFrame.sum) and none of the options work well for me. If I drop the `price` column and run `.sum(level=0)` it takes a long time. Look at the times of these two different methods(the faster one only sums the `quantity` column).

```
In [237]: %%timeit
     ...: df.groupby(['pk', 'name']).sum(level=0)
     ...: 
1 loop, best of 3: 3.04 s per loop

In [239]: %%timeit
     ...: df.groupby(['pk', 'name']).sum()
     ...: 
     ...: 
10 loops, best of 3: 42.4 ms per loop
```

The results are similar for `.sum(axis=1)`, too.

Comment: check your `dtypes`...

Comment: I just posted the type in response to piRSquared. They're Decimal

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Since you are using `decimal.Decimal` objects, the `numpy.sum` won't handle your objects. So, simply defer to the built-in `sum`:

```
In [18]: df
Out[18]:
   pk price       name  quantity transaction_amount
0  48   1.0  Product 1         1                1.0
1  48   1.0  Product 1         4                4.0
2  63   1.0  Product 2         2                2.0
3  63   1.0  Product 2         3                3.0
4  63   1.0  Product 2         1                1.0

In [19]: df.groupby(['pk', 'name']).aggregate({
    ...:     "quantity":np.sum,
    ...:     "price":sum,
    ...:     "transaction_amount":sum
    ...: })
Out[19]:
             price  quantity transaction_amount
pk name
48 Product 1   2.0         5                5.0
63 Product 2   3.0         6                6.0
```

Note, this will be slow, but it's the price you have to pay for using `object` dtype columns.

Comment: Thanks, this was indeed the problem. I wasn't making the connection to the Decimal type being relevant at all.

Comment: @CoryMadden `pandas` / `numpy` is built around *primitive arrays*, with fixed-size numeric types. While it works with `objects`, don't expect the built-in routines to play nice. And definitely don't expect it to be fast. Although, at least you keep the relative expressiveness and ease of *writing* pandas code.

Comment: I thought numpy was good for financial data, thus maintaining decimal places. I'd be ok casting it as a float, but it loses its accuracy.

Comment: As far as I know, `sum`, `np.sum` and `'sum'` are treated equally. The thing that makes this work is that you explicitly say that you want to take the sum of that column whereas groupby.sum excludes columns of object dtype. `df.groupby(['pk', 'name']).sum(numeric_only=False)` should also work in this case.

Comment: @ayhan I'm glad I looked back at this question. SO didn't alert me to it. This fixes it perfectly. Since I was thinking of Decimals as "numeric" I didn't try that.

Answer (score 3):

When I run

```
df.groupby(['pk', 'name']).sum()
```

I get

```
              price  quantity  transaction_amount
pk name                                          
48 Product 1    2.0         5                 5.0
63 Product 2    3.0         6                 6.0
```

Which indicates to me that your `price` and `transaction_amount` are objects.

Comment: They're Decimals. `In [251]: type(df.transaction_amount.iloc[0])
Out[251]: decimal.Decimal`

Comment: @CoryMadden Ok, so that implies that your *columns* are `dtype=object`. Are you using `decimal.Decimal` because you need the precision?

Comment: @juanpa.arrivillaga Yes, it's money. I'm able to  get the correct results when I call it in other manners, but I'd like to do it in a simpler manner.

Comment: @CoryMadden well, right off the bat I hope you realize your efficiency is going to be screwed. But, basically, `numpy` vectorized `.sum` isn't going to handle `decimal.Decimal` objects. Write your own `_sum` function, heck, or maybe even the built-in `sum` will do.

Comment: Ha! It's the transaction_amount column making it so damn slow. I can't believe I didn't make that connection. Well, I guess I already have the solution to my problem in my post...

Answer (score 1):

You can specify the columns to sum like this.

```
df.groupby(['pk','name'])['quantity','transaction_amount'].sum()
```

Comment: I've tried that, too, but it gives me the same result.