# Cannot Calculate Sum of Currency-Based Column Data in Pandas

Tags: python, python-3.x, pandas, numpy, data-science

I have the following CSV data:

```
+----------+-------------+-------+---------+
| Category | Part Number | Units |  Cost   |
+----------+-------------+-------+---------+
| Axel     |          78 |   587 | $159.95 |
| Rim      |          48 |   234 | $38.75  |
| Nut      |          39 |  1234 | $0.15   |
| Axel     |          79 |    67 | $110.95 |
+----------+-------------+-------+---------+
```

And the following code:

```
# Importing the libraries
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import pandas as pd

# Importing the dataset
df = pd.read_csv('stock.csv',engine="python")

#Sum of values by category
df.groupby('Category').sum()['Units']
df.groupby('Category').sum()['Cost']
```

When I run the second to last line, I get the following output:

```
df.groupby('Category').sum()['Units']
Out[4]: 
Category
Axel     654
Nut     1234
Rim      234
Name: Units, dtype: int64
```

When I run the last line, I get the following error:

```
KeyError: 'Cost'
```

I'm not sure if there is a simple way to sum the data without converting the data type to an integer and then converting it back.

Comment: `Cost` looks like a string to me. In which case...no. You can't add strings as numbers without converting them. If they're *not* strings you can do `sum(numeric_only=False)`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`.sum()` ignores all non-numeric columns. You've got to convert cost to numbers first:

```
df["Cost"] = df["Cost"].str[1:].astype(float)
```

Comment: I would suggest `Decimal` for adding money.

Comment: @CoryMadden `.sum()` converts `Decimal` to `float64`, anyway.

Comment: Even with `numeric_only=False`? Sorry for being lazy, but can you prove it? :) That seems like a very undesirable feature. I'm not sure I'm convinced, see my thread [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45472366/how-can-i-sum-two-different-columns-at-once-where-one-contains-decimal-objects-i). The math was very fast when I converted them to floats, but with `Decimal` it was very slow.

Comment: @CoryMadden Even worse: `df["Cost"].str[1:].astype(decimal.Decimal)` is treated as `object` and `.sum()` concatenates the string representations.  (Pandas version 0.18.1.) So, I retract my edit.

Comment: Did you try with `sum(numeric_only=False)`? That's how you sum `Decimal` columns.

Comment: @CoryMadden I did. `df["Cost"].str[1:].astype(decimal.Decimal).sum(numeric_only=False)` gives `'159.9538.750.15110.95'`.

Comment: Huh, as you can see from the thread I linked, I was definitely able to aggregate the `Decimal` types. It looks like I used `sum(level=0)` instead. I don't have that code anymore. Doing it in SQL was the obviously preferred route, especially since it maintains precision, but I wanted to play with pandas and test it.

Comment: `pd.DataFrame([[i, Decimal("%s.23" % i)] for i in range(10)])[1].sum()` outputs a `Decimal`.  Or you could use apply: `pd.DataFrame([[i, "%s.23" % i] for i in range(10)])[1].apply(lambda x: Decimal(x)).sum()`

Comment: @DYZ the line of code you wrote strips the first digit of each cost value so $159.95 becomes 59.95.

Comment: It strips the dollar sign. According to your example, the values begin with a $.

Comment: @DYZ, you are correct, I just double checked it. My mistake.